# Build changes not reflected in deployed app

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, vue.js, heroku

I have a Django/ Vue.js app that I deployed to Heroku. It's repo is connected to Heroku so I deploy it straight from the Heroku app.

I've updated the code and run `"npm run build"` afterward. I run `'git add *'`, checkd that every files where tracked, commit them and push them to the repo.

Afterward I did a `manual deploy` from the Heroku app. Deployment went fine but the changes are not reflected into my deployed app.

What went wrong? Did my build failed (had no error message while building and I did get the 'build Complet' message)

I don't know where to look at. How can I be sure the changes I made are reflected into my build?

What I tried:

-deleting the build folders and `"run build"` again with no luck

-force my browser to clean the cache with no luck either

What I did:

I wanted to change my login/logout url redirection

Comment: any cache in the middle? what kind of changes are not reflected? did you tried to clean the browser cache?

Comment: Question edited